# (Django) Efficiently get related objects from a ManyToManyField, sorted and limited to a count

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a database of > 50k Persons. Each Person can own multiple Items, and each Item can be owned by multiple Persons. Person contains field Items, which is of type ManyToManyField().

I need to get 100 Person objects, sorted by number of Items owned. Also for each Person I need 10 Items, sorted by a "rarity" field (just a number).

The problem is that the first part of the query (getting the Person objects) is really fast, and the second part takes 100 times longer, which makes sense because I can see it makes a separate query for each Person.

Here is my code:

```py
persons = Person.objects.all().order_by('-items_count')[:100]

for person in persons:
    items = person.items.all().order_by('rarity')[:10]

    # Do stuff, build a response object
```

`items_count` is a precomputed field with number of Items owned. I know I can annotate it on the fly, I was just experimenting to optimize the query.

The whole thing takes over a second. Is there a way to combine both queries into one, or change my models somehow to optimize this?

Here are my models:

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # Other fields...

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name='owners')
    # Other fields...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [`QuerySet.prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). Examples in documentation explain the usage pretty well.

I think it should look similar to this:

```py
persons = Person.objects.all().prefetch_related("items")
```

Comment: I got it to work, but as soon as I try to sort the related items it does another query. I couldn't find a way to include sorting or other query parameters in `prefetch_related`.

Comment: The `Prefetch` object should handle this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch

Comment: I made it work, but it had no effect on performance. I'm seeing the server makes only one query, but it takes just as long as all queries combined from before.

Comment: Interesting. Could you show how the query looks like in the SQL terms? You can do that via `print(queryset.query)`.